# Python <`No such file or directory: 'gs'> error *UPDATE*

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have implemented the following `save` function in my program which allows the user to save as a JPEG file whatever he/she draws on the Tkinter canvas with the Turtle. How it is supposed to work is that it first captures the screen and Tkinter canvas and then creates a postscript file based on it. Then it converts that postscript file as a PIL (Python Imaging Library) readable file type, and then the PIL saves the converted file as a JPEG. My save function is shown below:

```
def savefirst(): 
    # Capture screen and Tkinter canvas
    cnv = getscreen().getcanvas() 
    global hen
    # Save screen and canvas as Postscript file
    ps = cnv.postscript(colormode = 'color')
    # Open a Tkinter file dialog that allows to input his.her own name for the file
    hen = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension = '.jpg')
    # Convert Postscript file to PIL readable format
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8')))
    # Finally save converted file as a JPEG
    im.save(hen + '.jpg')
```

However, whenever I run this save function, I get the error shown below:

```
line 2396, in savefirst
    im.save(hen + '.jpg')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1646, in save
    self.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 337, in load
    self.im = Ghostscript(self.tile, self.size, self.fp, scale)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py", line 143, in Ghostscript
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1544, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs'
```

**What is `'gs'`, why is this happening, and how would I fix the issue causing this error?**

**FYI:** Just in case you need to know, my operating system is Macintosh and my Python version is 3.5.1

**EDIT:** Apparently, just as I thought, `'gs'` means GhostScript, and that error was occurring because I had to install it (Thanks to the answer for making me realize that). I have installed the .dmg from [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/), **but I still keep on getting the error**. Maybe it has something to do with my current OS (Mac OS 10.11.2)? Or something else is wrong with my save function? I honestly do not know. **Anyways, why does this error keep on occurring even though I have (hopefully) installed GhostScript?** Again, any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIL delegates PostScript file creation to GhostScript, which is not installed on your system. Install it.

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought it was. Just wanted to make sure. However, I have searched around a lot, but I cannot find a GhostScript version compatible with my Python version (3.5.1). I have even done `pip install GhostScript` in Terminal, but I still get this error.

Comment: GhostScript is a completely separate application. It does not need to be compatible with Python.

Comment: Wait, GhostScript is NOT a module for Python?

Comment: No. It is a complete standalone PostScript engine.

Comment: Well, I have gone to the GhostScript website, and yes, you are right. However, there are 4 downloads. Which one should I get for PostScript conversion?

Comment: The one that provides a working `gs` executable for your system. No, I have no idea which one that is.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, issue: I have installed it, but I am still getting the same error. Is there anything else I am doing wrong?

Comment: `gs` or a symlink to it has to be in one of the directories given in `$PATH`.

Comment: I have gotten it using the .dmg at http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/ However, I am still getting this error. How would I fix it?

Comment: Apparently the `'gs'` directory is not getting installed, even though I have already installed GhostScript.

Comment: I read the article you put in your profile. Very interesting article, and I will try to keep in mind to try my best to solve the issue, which I already do. I really don't want to come here as I really want to accomplish as much as I can on my own. However, sometimes I have to with my very small scope of understanding in the Computer Science field. Thus, coming on Stack Overflow and asking questions is not just me wanting to solve my issue, but **it is also my chance to expand my horizons**, to learn the MANY things there are to know about the science of computers and Python itself.

Comment: So, I hope you understand why I asked so many questions, especially since I am just a teen (not that that makes me any more special than adults) who is really intrigued with the science behind computers and the many languages that such a simple object in the universe can understand.

Comment: Anyways, that is a great article.